# Patching security vulnerability SC2016-002-136135 for versions 7.2 and above

Tags: configuration

I am trying to patch my sitecore instance by following the sitecore knowledge base article https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/039942

I am on sitecore 8.1 update 3 and could not able to do below step as i cannot find that in web.config file?

Edit the web.config file and locate this line within the '/configuration/system.web/httpHandlers' node

```
<add verb="*" path="sitecore_icon.ashx" type="Sitecore.Resources.IconRequestHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" />
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably running the site in integrated mode. This means you don't need the /configuration/system.web part, which is for classic mode. If it is not there, you can ignore that step.

Comment: This triggered me to learn more about classic and integrated mode. thanks.

Answer (score 9):

The `httpModules` and `httpHandlers` sections were removed from the default `web.config` in Sitecore 8.1 Initial Release.

From the [release notes](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/Sitecore%2081/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2081%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes):

> The outdated sections `<httpModules>` and `<httpHandlers>` have been removed from the Web.config file. (437095)

Sitecore recommends you run the site in Integrated mode and is the default installation mode when using the Sitecore installer or SIM.

The step you mentioned is only valid for older Sitecore installations, you can ignore it for Sitecore 8.1 and above.